# keep the space between words in notepad++ after deleting all not Arabic words in text

Tags: text, notepad++

i have Arabic text and contains English and other characters, i tried this regular expression in notepad++ and it's works:

```
[^\x{0600}-\x{06ff}]
```

but it;s delete all the spaces between words. so how can i delete these letters and keep the space between the words.

thank you
here is an example :

```
"السيارة، أو تركب مع سائق أجنبي؟ صيد الفوائد saaid.net الرئيسة اعرف نبيك العلماء وطلبة العلم"
```

after using regular expression, it becomes

```
قىالعلماءوالدعاةتراجمالعلماءوالدعاةهواتفالعلماءوالدعاةأرقاممكاتبالدعوةوقفةمعالأحداثتبرئةالمناهجالليبراليةفيالميزانالشيخمحم
```

so the space between words got deleted !

Comment: You might want to add a blank to the regular expression like in `[^\x{0600}-\x{06ff} ]` (note the added blank at the end).

Comment: What exactly are you doing ? Regex replace ? And what is the expected output ?

Comment: Regex replace, i have an Arabic text which contains English and other characters, so i tries to delete these characters using notepad++ .... however i tried using this expression [^\x{0600}-\x{06ff}] ...it's works but delete the space between words.......so i just figured out....i just use this [^\x{0600}-\x{06ff}] and replace with any thing like a...then replace a with single space.....so i got the space between words.